# What will happens if we specify Spring bean scope in a class using annotation and in xml both?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Suppose I am a controller and for this controller I have specify the bean scope in xml as singleton and then accidentally I have specify the bean scope using annotation inside the class as well as prototype.

What will happens when I will restart the server. Will it take the scope from xml or from class

Comment: That totally depends on what and how you are loading things.

Comment: Can you please elaborate in detail please.